# How can i create ajax search in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
I want create a ajax search in laravel 5.2 and value echo table tr
bt how can i done my work??
```

my code is ok bt not echo table tr..please help me   I want create a ajax search in laravel 5.2 and value echo table tr
    bt how can i done my work?? 
my code is ok bt not echo table tr..please help me
     
            
                
                    
                    Ajax Search

```
            </head>
            <body >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <form>
                            <span>Given Text</span>

                            <input type="text" id="search_text" onkeyup="search_data(this.value, 'result');">

                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <hr/>
                            <span id="result"></span>

                        </form>

                    </div>
                    <table style="width:100%">
               <tr>
                   <th>Std Name</th>
                   <th>Std Email</th>
                   <th>Std Number</th>
               </tr>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($tbl)):
                            foreach ($tbl as $std_value):
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $std_value->student_name ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $std_value->student_email ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $std_value->student_name ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach;
                        endif;
                        ?>
                    </table> 
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!--
               //Create a boolean variable to check for a valid Internet Explorer instance.
                    var xmlhttp = false;
                    //Check if we are using IE.
                    try {
                        //If the Javascript version is greater than 5.
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                        //alert(xmlhttp);
                        //alert ("You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer.");
                    } catch (e) {
                        //alert(e);

                        //If not, then use the older active x object.
                        try {
                            //If we are using Internet Explorer.
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            //alert ("You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer");
                        } catch (E) {
                            //alert(E);
                            //Else we must be using a non-IE browser.
                            xmlhttp = false;
                        }
                    }
                    //If we are using a non-IE browser, create a javascript instance of the object.
                    //alert(typeof XMLHttpRequest);
                    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        //alert ("You are not using Microsoft Internet Explorer");
                    }
          function search_data(search_text, objID)
                    {
                        //alert(given_text);
                        //var obj = document.getElementById(objID);
                        serverPage = '{!! URL::to("/search-data")!!}?text=' + search_text;
                        xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
                        {
                            //alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
                            //alert(xmlhttp.status);
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                            {
                                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                                document.getElementById(objID).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                //document.getElementById(objcw).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            }
                        }
                        xmlhttp.send(null);
                    }

                    //-->
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
    //Controller
     public function data_search() {
            $search_text = $_GET['text'];
            if($search_text==NULL){
               $data= Tbl_Student::all();

            }
            else{
              $data=Tbl_Student::where('student_name','LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
             }
             return view('ajax.ajax_search')->with('tbl',$data);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many places where you need to change the code.

1. I Assume that you want to populate the TABLE with Student information via Ajax right? But you have written the Code as if there will be a Full View rendering. You shouldn't.
2. As per your code, even if it return the result, the result will get populated into your SPAN element `<span id="result"></span>` not the TABLE
3. For Ajax requests you are supposed to return the JSON Response, not the 'View'.
   Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses

It would be better, to refer some of the code where the Ajax based actions have been done, so that you get the idea.

Kindly refer the following blog posts, which will help you in getting the clear idea about Ajax Requests with Laravel.

- http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-ajax-tutorial

Note: I just have one suggestion. As of now you are using the XMLHttp object for Ajax handling and normal Javascript. Would be good if you can use the jQuery, which will help you to write the better Ajax code as well as handle the Ajax Response in a nicer way.

Comment: What's the difference between javascript ajax vs jquery ajax??
suggest me whose path is easy

Comment: The underlying principle is same, but with Plain Javascript, you need to takecare of creating the XHLHttp Object, for different versions of browsers and handle the request. jQuery does all this kind of heavy lifting for you and makes your life easy.

For Example, your whole JavaScript Ajax functionality can be written in jQuery as  


    ` $.ajax({url: "AJAX_CONTROLLER_URL", success: function(result){
            $("#objectId").html(result);
        }});`

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to something like this

```
<body >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form>
                <span>Given Text</span>
                <input type="text" id="search_text" onkeyup="search_data(this.value, 'result');">
                <br/>
                <hr/>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div id="table-results">
            @include('student-table')
         </div>
    </div>
```

notice we are going to include another template

```
<div id="table-results">
    @include('student-table')
</div>
```

now create this student-table.blade.php file

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Std Name</th>
        <th>Std Email</th>
        <th>Std Number</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach( $results as $student )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $student->student_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->student_email}}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->student_number }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Here is the jQuery (much easier than plain javascript for this)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search_data(search_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search-data/' + search_value,
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response){
        $('#table-results').html(response);          // put the returning html in the 'results' div
    });
}
</script>
```

in your controller, change the return

```
return view('student-table')->with('results',$data);
```

so, your ajax call will cause your controller to find the data and return it in a view which your ajax function will put into the 'results' div when it completes.